# ¿Por qué el método routes() no es reconocido en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, passport

Estoy trabajando con laravel passport, hice proyecto desde cero siguendo este tutorial básico: [enlace](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-rest-api-with-passport-authentication-tutorial/) pero cuando hago la prueba me salta este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A qué se debe este error, ya no funciona ese método en laravel?

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].